# Где скачать пакеты драйверов для принтеров марок Canon и Epson для RedHat 7?

Tags: linux, принтер, redhat, cups

Для сервиса печати CUPS мне нужно найти и установить пакеты драйверов для принтеров Epson и Canon. Я нашел где скачать драйвера у производителей, но не нашел у них возможности скачать пакетом все драйвера, только по одному. Может кто-то знает где можно их скачать?

Comment: сами-то файлы с т.н. «драйверами» аккумулируются на сайте openprinting.org. ну а мэйнтэйнеры дистрибутивов уже опакетируют их. вам, видимо, не хватает более свежего пакета cups (ну или как он там зовётся в репозиториях redhat). для начала убедитесь, что нужные вам файлы на сайте имеются: https://www.openprinting.org/printers , а дальше уже действуйте по обстоятельствам.